# Trying to find the largest palindrome created by multiplying two three-digit numbers, how can I improve this program?

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I've built a program to solve Project Euler problem #4.

The problem is: "find the largest number that is a palindrome created by multiplying two three-digit numbers." With all my figuring and help from colleagues, it's come to this but still returns ''). Can somebody explain to me what's wrong with this program? It's in JavaScript.

**Create function**

```
    function lgst_palindrome_3dgt(){
    //create array
    palindromes = []
    x = 100
    y = 100
    //while 999 > x > 100
    while (x <= 999){
      //set y to equal x as to reset y and keep from repeating iterations
      y = x
      //while 100 < y < 999, check if number is a palindrome
      while (y <= 999){
        var numString2 = (x*y)toString()
        var splitNumber2 = numString2.split("")
        var reversedArray2 = splitNumber2.reverse()
        var backwardString2 = reversedArray2.join('')
        var backwardNumber2 = parseInt(backwardString2)
        if (backwardNumber2 - (x*y) === 0){
          palindromes.push(x*y)
        }
        //then increment y
        y++
      }
      //after incrementing y to 999, increment x, then start the loop again
      x++
    }
    //return the last entry in palindromes
    return palindromes.pop()
}
console.log(lgst_palindrome_3dgt())
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify toString(), capitalize S.

```js
var numString2 = (x*y).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working!

```js
function lgst_palindrome_3dgt(){

palindromes = [];
x = 10;
y = 10;

while (x <= 999){
  y = x;
  while (y <= 999){
    var numString2 = (x*y).toString();
    var splitNumber2 = numString2.split("");
    var reversedArray2 = splitNumber2.reverse();
    var backwardString2 = reversedArray2.join('');
    var backwardNumber2 = parseInt(backwardString2);

    if (backwardNumber2 - (x * y) === 0){
      palindromes.push(x * y);
    }
    y++;
  }
  x++;
}
console.log(palindromes);
return "the largest palindrome number is: " + palindromes.pop();
} 

console.log(lgst_palindrome_3dgt());
```

Comment: I fixed the program to match yours, and I copied and pasted your answer, and I'm still not getting a result. Did this work on your machine?